# Angular PWA App: How to handle "Minimize main-thread work" and "Reduce JavaScript execution time" suggestion from page speed insights

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, single-page-application, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have an angular PWA app. It shows lots of content on the start page, so it needs to load the content from the server. This takes some time, and lots of Javascript work has to be done.

Google Page speed insights rates page with 10/100. It shows "Minimize main-thread work 12.4 s" and "Reduce JavaScript execution time 7.7 s" as important changes I should do.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. SEO agencys told me that this has a very bad impact on my website ranking. Is this really true? Does google really downrank PWA SPAs for loading everything at the start? I mean, it`s not really a good idea to put normal websites in one bucket with a PWA SPA app, which needs a bit to load at start, but is then really fast
2. What possibilities exist, to optimize this for a PWA SPA. I mean, SPAs always need a lot of things to do at startup. I have no idea how to optimize that?

A few examples for PWA from big companies, which also are really bad rated in page speed insights.

- [Starbucks](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-app-starbucks-com/kv1wcwa6ry?hl=DE&form_factor=mobile)
- [Pintrest](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-pinterest-de/pkuab5w4kt?hl=DE&form_factor=mobile)
- [Debenhams](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-debenhams-com/4mwl97tulb?hl=DE&form_factor=mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, loading time does impact ranking, and SPAs are really bad for that.

One approach you could take is to have a regular website for the content you want to be indexed, and a PWA that is installed if the user wants to go that way (both can be on the same domain).

The advantage is that from Google's and the random visitor's point of view, it's a normal and fast multi-page website. But once installed, it's a real, dynamic PWA. The downside is that it requires more work.

If you prefer to keep everything as one SPA PWA only, then I'd suggest looking into code splitting and lazy loading, and organizing your code so that you only load the minimum required initially, and then the rest of the code only when it's used.

One last thing to consider that will have a significant boost is to use web workers to do the heavy work instead of the main thread. For example, if you have to make API calls, it's better to do them in web workers and then update the main thread once you have the data locally, because it's really smooth.